# Two unsorted single linked list to one sorted single linked list

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

Given two unsorted single linked list of size `M` and `N`. The task is to create a single sorted linked list. No new nodes should be created.
I have thought of two approaches.

## Approach 1:

Sort each list individually in MlogM and NlogN. Then merge two sorted lists.
Time complexity: O( MlogM + NlogN )

## Approach 2:

Attach the second list to the end of first list. Then sort the list.
Time Complexity: O( (M + N) log(M + N) )

Which approach is better?
Is there still any better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asymptotically speaking - it is the same.

if `n<m` then:

```
O(nlogn+ mlogm) = O(mlogm)
and 
O(n+m)log(n+m)) = O(nlog(n+m) + mlog(n+m)) = O(nlog(m) + mlog(m)) = O(mlogm)
```

Symetrically, if `m<n` both are `O(nlogn)`

In fact, for `n=m`, approach 1 is the first step of [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Comment: Yet in terms of implementation the second approach is better. It requires one call to a `sort` function, while the first approach would require both a `sort` and a `merge` subroutine.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov: I agree, but note that ff you are going for mergesort - you are going to have implementing `merge()` anyway...

Comment: In terms of multicore processing, the first method is easier to parallelize (trivially, you can `sort()` the two lists in parallel)

Answer (score 0):

In any case, approch 1 is the good. See this calculations, if

- n=2 and m=3 nlogn = 0.60, mlogm = 1.43, nlogn + mlogm = 2.03 while
  (n+m)log(n+m) = 3.49
- n=2 and m=30 nlogn = 0.60, mlogm = 44.31, nlogn + mlogm = 44.91 while
  (n+m)log(n+m) = 48.16
- n=2 and m=300 nlogn = 0.60, mlogm = 743.14, nlogn + mlogm = 743.74
  while (n+m)log(n+m) = 748.96
- n=2 and m=3000 nlogn = 0.60, mlogm = 10,431.36, nlogn + mlogm =
  10,431.96 while (n+m)log(n+m) = 10,439.18
- n=2 and m=30000 nlogn = 0.60, mlogm = 134,313.64, nlogn + mlogm =
  134,314.24 while (n+m)log(n+m) = 134,323.46
- n=2 and m=300000 nlogn = 0.60 ,mlogm = 1,643,136.38, nlogn + mlogm = 
  1,643,136.98  while (n+m)log(n+m) = 1,643,148.19

Because, clear reason behind this is:in any case,

```
(n+m) > n & (n+m) > m
log (n+m) >= log n
log (n+m) >= log m
```

While in the case of n=m,

```
nlogn + mlogm = 2m logm
              = log m (power of 2m)
(n+m) log(n+m) = 2m log (2m)
               = log 2m (power of 2m)
and m(power of 2m) < 2m(power of 2m)
```

The only simple reason to choose first approch is, **it is less time consuming to sort a small array of data compare to big large array**.